# Create a bingo game using java

Tags: java, arrays, random

I want to create a bingo game using arrays, methods in java. But I totally have no idea about how to get start it. Can someone give me some key tips for me to get start it? Like, how do I use the random class to generate a series of numbers in an array? Here is the part of the question:

The first column consists of integers from 1 to 15, the second column consists of integers from 16 to 30, the third column consists of
integers from 31 to 45, the fourth column consists of integers from 46 to 60, and the last
column consists of integers from 61 to 75. Note that the numbers are not repeated.

So, how do I create a list of numbers in a range of 1 to 15 in column 1 within an array?

Comment: Hmm. Nice assignment, but you really should limit the text to your question (which is about random numbers, right?) and show us what you've done so far, where you got stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We generally don't help with school assignments but here are some hints.

```
(int)(Math.random()*74)+1 will create a random number between 0 and 75.
```

you can create the table you want with `int table[][] = new int[5][5];`

And then use a loop to find if the card has been cleared.

You might also want to create a second 2d boolean table to store which numbers have already been found.

Comment: Yeah, what I need is just so hints for me to get start it, thx a lot.

Comment: What do you have so far? Do you have any experience programming in Java(or at all)? Have you downloaded something like eclipse yet? Do you know how a for loop works? Do you understand variables? Show us what you have and we can help.

Comment: I use Jcreator for programming and I know all those knowledge you mentioned above. i just don't how to link them together. I want to use Object-oriented programming style to make a bingo game. What i have so far is just some methods I may have to use.  CallNumber method(call a number between 1 to 75), findCard1 method(determine whether the number called is in card 1 ),findCard2 method(determine whether the number called is in card 2 ), setZero method(set the element to 0 if either number is found in either card1 or card2),

Comment: getWinner method(if sum =0, return winner(if found all-0 row, or an all-0 column, or an all-0 diagonal)), displayArray method(display the array after the winner is found), that's the blueprint I have right now, just want to know how do I link them together to make this program works.

Comment: Alright you need to start with a main 

'public static void main(String [ ] args)
{"your code"}'

Do you know how to make a GUI yet? It really helps a lot if you properly explain what you need.  

But basically what you need to program in order is this:
1 create the 2d arrays with numbers (the int table[][] line)
2 write code that fills the cards(you can make these cards their own objects if you want or keep them as global variables)
3 you then create a large loop that repeats every turn 
4 within this loop you need to create a draw random number

Comment: 5 You then write code that removes said random number from your card (perhaps using a 2nd 2d boolean array or by setting the values of taken numbers to -1)
6 you write code that checks if a bingo has been reached this is probably easiest to do with a large number of for loops. 
7 you close your loops and are now done.
First finish any part of the program before moving to the next and as this is a school assignment ask your teacher for help.

Answer (score 0):

When I help my friends in programming, I generally tell that the best thing is to separate each requirement and implement it completely and only then move to the next one.

In your case, the best thing would be to generate all the random 1-75 unique numbers and store them successfully. As @Thijser said, Math.random or even the Random object are useful here.

You could perform all checks in a single dimensional array and set the cards as two-dimensional arrays (`int[]` and `int[][]` respectively).

Since you have to mark the 'point', (e.g you have the called number in your card), you could even try to use a three dimensional array, though it may be a little hard to maintain.

If you try the 120% mark, it will simplify the handling of cards, so keep that in mind.